# Why is the object called "module" not callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, praw

I'm trying to make a bot that replies to comments on Reddit but I've been getting this error and I don't know what to do

this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\Reddit Bot\bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    r = praw.reddit(user_agent = "Replyer Bot")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I've imported praw, time and random separated by colons if that helps

Comment: Any code lines ? will be helpful to analyze. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in `r = praw.reddit(user_agent = "Replyer Bot")`. Use:

```
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent = "Replyer Bot")
```

Take a look at the [Quick Start page](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html)